# CloudSim: need way to introduce performance degradation in VMs at certain simulation time

Tags: java, qos, cloudsim

In Cloudsim, I need to introduce SLA violation at a particular time of the simulation e.g. from 600 to 1200 and from 2400 to 4000 (just an example). Such SLA violation needs to show a shortfall of mips from 600-1200 and 2400-4000 simulation times so that the vms allocates less mips than the "requested mips" for these time intervals.
I have seen the example VmSchedulerTimeSharedOverSubscription.java of Cloudsim where it deploys lots of vms following either random or predetermined dataset. This example is not helping me.

Can anyone give any idea to introduce such QoS shortfall for only some time intervals rather the entire simulation lifetime in Cloudsim? or briefly "Is there any way to introduce performance degradation in VMs by allocates less mips than the requested mips at certain simulation time in Cloudsim?"

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way is to develop a performance model (some sort of distribution), and then reduce the number of allocated MIPS in VMSchedular class, accordingly.